# CakePHP multiple controllers use same models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

In CakePHP 2.5 I have these controllers:

```
 - CommonsController extends AppController { ... }   
 - MyController extends CommonsController { ... }    
 - GoodController extends CommonsController { ... }
```

I have this Models:

```
 - Work1 extends AppModel  { ... }  
 - Work2 extends AppModel  { ... }  
 - Work3 extends AppModel  { ... }
```

Inside my CommonsController, I have 45 methods that uses Work1, Work2, Work3 models.

```
  - CommonsController::method1() { // using Work1 model }  
  - CommonsController::method2() { // using Work1 model }  
  ....
  - CommonsController::method16() { // using Work2 model }  
  - CommonsController::method17() { // using Work2 model }  
  ....
  - CommonsController::method44() { // using Work3 model }  
  - CommonsController::method45() { // using Work3 model }
```

With this structure Inside controller I can call models like this:

```
   // inside CommonsController
   $this->method18();
   $this->method26();

   // inside MyController
   $this->method18();
   $this->method42();

   // inside GoodController
   $this->method18();
   $this->method36();
```

In CakePHP for the common controller functions I use Components. Is there a structure to use common models in controllers ?

Comment: What do you mean by _a structure to use common models in controller_? To use a model in a controller you use the **$uses** variable. FWIW: I don't think your controllers should be using that many models _that are not inter-related_. (Once you can use one model, you can use all other models related to the first one.)

Comment: Multiple controllers can use same Coponent code. I search to use multiple model code inside different controllers.

Comment: _to use multiple model code inside different controllers_:: In order to run any model's code (that is, you want to execute a specific model's method) from within a controller, all you need to is put that model's name within the **$uses** variable. For example in your controller you could have `public $uses = array('Recipe', 'User');` which allows you to use the Recipe and User model's methods. To execute them use `$this->Recipe->recipeMethod()`